# ngtable inline-editing , can't add row?

Tags: angularjs, ngtable

Getting my head around the ng-table grid. Stuck at the point how to add a new row:

```
$scope.addRow = function(add) {
      $scope.data.push(add)
      $scope.showAdd = false;
};
```

Trying to add the new object to the data array but does not work? what is wrong here?

html:

```
<table class="noborder">
    <tr>
        <td rowspan="2">ID: {{add.id}}<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{add.id}}"></td>
        <td>Firstname:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="fn" class="w100" ng-model="add.fn"></td>
        <td>Description: </td>
        <td>Email:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="em" class="w180" ng-model="add.em"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value=" save " ng-click="addRow(p);"></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Lastname:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ln" class="w100" ng-model="add.ln"></td>
        <td><input type="text" name="dc" class="w180" ng-model="add.dc"></td>
        <td>Phone: </td>
        <td><input type="text" name="ph" class="w120" ng-model="add.ph"></td>
        <td><input type="button" value=" cancel" ng-click="cancelEdit()"></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is a plunkr ref: http://plnkr.co/edit/9woANV?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

In addRow.html you are adding variable 'p' which always evaluates as null. Change this to 'add'.

e.g.

```
ng-click="addRow(add);"
```

plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/xEL78EZNGrD6GxE029X8?p=preview